# C# Populate Inner Object with data retrieved from stored procedure

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }

        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public PhoneNumber BusinessPhone { get; set; }
        public PhoneNumber ResidencePhone { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see from the above that I have `Person` class that contains `PhoneNumber` object. The `PhoneNumber` class will has this definition:

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
        public string AreaCode { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
}
```

Now to populate the `Person` object, I am getting the data from the stored procedure like this:

```
_context.PersonDetails.FromSqlRaw<Person>("EXEC [GetPersonDetails] @personId={0}", personId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPersonDetails
    @personId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1 
        FirstName, LastName,
        FirmNameCust,
        Addr1, Addr2,
        City, [State],
        ZipCode,
        FirmNameCust [Company],
        Addr1 as AddressLine1,
        Addr2 as AddressLine2,
        City as City,
        State as State,
        ZipCode as ZipCode,
        ResAreaCode as ResidentialAreaCode, 
        ResPhone as ResidentialPhone,
        ResExt as ResidentialExtension, 
        BusAreaCode as BusinessAreaCode,
        BusPhone as BusinessPhone,
        BusExt as BusinessExtension
    FROM
        Person 
    WHERE
        personId = @personId
```

Based on the above code, how can I populate the phone number objects with the info from the stored procedure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've structured your Person it's actually more like there should be a separate table with phone numbers in and a relationship between Person and PhoneNumber

That said, don't forget that EF just sets props it sees and those props could easily be backed by something else rather than being simple props on class X

```
public class Person{

  public PhoneNumber BusinessPhone {get;set;} = new();

  public string BusinessAreaCode {
    get => BusinessPhone.AreaCode;
    set => BusinessPhone.AreaCode = value;
  }
```

By the time EF has finished mapping your result set to your entity the BusinessPhone details will be populated..

If you don't like the idea that you have these extra props hanging around, don't forget that eF can populate an object using a constructor too..